# Что происходит в этом куске кода?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Таблица confirmed [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И далее такой код

```
confirmed.isnull().sum().where(lambda x : x!=0).dropna()
```

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, что делает этот код?

Comment: Похоже на кривую попытку показать только столбцы содержащие NaN вместе с числом NaN в столбцах. Но проще всего запустить и посмотреть что получится...

Answer (score 1):

Данное выражение показывает количество `NaN` значений в столбцах. Столбцы, в которых `NaN` отсутствуют, удаляются.

---

Пояснение на примере датасета о пассажирах Титаника:

Исходный датасет:

```
In [26]: df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\work\ML\titanic\train.csv")

In [27]: df.head(3)
Out[27]:
   PassengerId  Survived  Pclass                                     Name     Sex  ...  Parch            Ticket  \
0            1         0       3                  Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  ...      0         A/5 21171
1            2         1       1  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence...  female  ...      0          PC 17599
2            3         1       3                   Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  ...      0  STON/O2. 3101282

      Fare Cabin  Embarked
0   7.2500   NaN         S
1  71.2833   C85         C
2   7.9250   NaN         S

[3 rows x 12 columns]
```

---

Выражение из вопроса:

```
In [28]: df.isnull().sum().where(lambda x: x!=0).dropna()
Out[28]:
Age         177.0
Cabin       687.0
Embarked      2.0
dtype: float64
```

Теперь пошагово:

```
In [31]: df.isnull()
Out[31]:
     PassengerId  Survived  Pclass   Name    Sex  ...  Parch  Ticket   Fare  Cabin  Embarked
0          False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False   True     False
1          False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False  False     False
2          False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False   True     False
3          False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False  False     False
4          False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False   True     False
..           ...       ...     ...    ...    ...  ...    ...     ...    ...    ...       ...
886        False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False   True     False
887        False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False  False     False
888        False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False   True     False
889        False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False  False     False
890        False     False   False  False  False  ...  False   False  False   True     False

[891 rows x 12 columns]

In [32]: df.isnull().sum()
Out[32]:
PassengerId      0
Survived         0
Pclass           0
Name             0
Sex              0
Age            177
SibSp            0
Parch            0
Ticket           0
Fare             0
Cabin          687
Embarked         2
dtype: int64

In [33]: df.isnull().sum().where(lambda x: x!=0)
Out[33]:
PassengerId      NaN
Survived         NaN
Pclass           NaN
Name             NaN
Sex              NaN
Age            177.0
SibSp            NaN
Parch            NaN
Ticket           NaN
Fare             NaN
Cabin          687.0
Embarked         2.0
dtype: float64

In [34]: df.isnull().sum().where(lambda x: x!=0).dropna()
Out[34]:
Age         177.0
Cabin       687.0
Embarked      2.0
dtype: float64
```

То есть, данное выражение показывает сколько значений `NaN` в столбцах - столбцы, в которых `NaN` отсутствуют удаляются.

---

Альтернативное решение:

```
In [38]: df.isna().sum().loc[lambda ser: ser>0]
Out[38]:
Age         177
Cabin       687
Embarked      2
dtype: int64
```